# Умножение в столбик - проблема с отступами. Java

Tags: java

Стоит задача перемножить в столбик два числа. Всё получилось, кроме отступов, чтобы все выглядело красиво.

Из основного класса LongMultiplication.java:

```
package info.sjd;

import info.sjd.service.*;

public class LongMultiplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LongMultiplicationService.printLongMultiplication(1234, 123);
    }
}
```

Вызываю методы из сервисного класса:

```
package info.sjd.service;

public class LongMultiplicationService {
    // Задаем отступ слева
    private static int shiftNumber = 20;

    //  Метод возвращает более длинное из двух чисел
    public static int findLongerNumber(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        int longerNumber = 0;
        if (String.valueOf(firstNumber).length() < String.valueOf(secondNumber).length()) {
            longerNumber = secondNumber;
        } else {
            longerNumber = firstNumber;
        }
        return longerNumber;
    }

    //  Метод возвращает более короткое из двух чисел
    public static int findShorterNumber(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        int shorterNumber = 0;
        if (String.valueOf(firstNumber).length() > String.valueOf(secondNumber).length()) {
            shorterNumber = secondNumber;
        } else {
            shorterNumber = firstNumber;
        }
        return shorterNumber;
    }

    // Метод печатает нужное количество нужных символов подряд без перевода строки в конце
    public static void repeatNSymbols(int n, String symbol) {
        String resultString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            resultString += symbol;
        }
        System.out.print(resultString);     
    }

    // Метод печатает нужное количество нужных символов подряд с переводом строки в конце
    public static void repeatNSymbolsNewLine (int n, String symbol) {
        String resultString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            resultString += symbol;

        }
        System.out.print(resultString); 
        System.out.println("");
    }

    // Метод печатает промежуточные вычисления - произведения первого числа на каждый из разрядов второго числа
    public static void intermediateMultiplication(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {

        int rightShift = 1;
        while (secondNumber > 0) {
            System.out.println(firstNumber * (secondNumber % 10));
            secondNumber /= 10;
            repeatNSymbols(shiftNumber - rightShift, " ");
            rightShift++;
        }
        repeatNSymbols(1, " ");
    }
    // Метод сводит всё в одну конструкцию
    public static void printLongMultiplication(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        repeatNSymbols(shiftNumber, " ");
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(findLongerNumber(firstNumber, secondNumber)));
        repeatNSymbols(shiftNumber - 1, " ");
        System.out.println("x");
        repeatNSymbols(shiftNumber, " ");
        repeatNSymbols(String.valueOf(findLongerNumber(firstNumber, secondNumber)).length() - String.valueOf(findShorterNumber(firstNumber, secondNumber)).length(), " ");
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(findShorterNumber(firstNumber, secondNumber)));
        repeatNSymbols(shiftNumber, " ");
        repeatNSymbolsNewLine(String.valueOf(findLongerNumber(firstNumber, secondNumber)).length(), "_");
        repeatNSymbols(shiftNumber, " ");
        intermediateMultiplication(findLongerNumber(firstNumber, secondNumber), findShorterNumber(firstNumber, secondNumber));
        repeatNSymbolsNewLine(String.valueOf(String.valueOf(firstNumber * secondNumber)).length(), "_");
        repeatNSymbols(shiftNumber - (String.valueOf(findLongerNumber(firstNumber, secondNumber)).length() - String.valueOf(findShorterNumber(firstNumber, secondNumber)).length()) - 1, " ");
        System.out.println(firstNumber * secondNumber);
    }
}
```

Я запутался и не могу понять, как организовать сдвижку строчек влево для произвольных чисел. Пока что получается "подгонять" под конкретную пару - только тогда выглядит "красиво".

Как, оперируя длинами двух чисел и промежуточных произведений одного из них на каждый из разрядов другого, сделать чтобы было красиво в общем случае, для чисел произвольной длины?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавил картинку для понимания проблемы. Т.е. сейчас я просто подогнал сдвижку под случай 1234х123 и все выглядит ровно по правому краю. А вот когда перемножаются другие числа - начинается разнобой.

Comment: Создай переменные String shorter, longer, а не вычисляй их длинными строками каждый раз. Тогда самому разобраться легче будет

Comment: а что выводит не подскажете?

Comment: michael_best, добавил скриншоты в самом низу поста с вопросом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант.
Вы задаете отступ фиксировано = 20, а нужно отталкиваться от ширины, так как по факту мы привязаны к правому краю, хотя и печатаем слева направо.

Максимальная ширина всего столбца будет как длина результата +1, чтобы еще знак умножения влез. Теперь от этой ширины отталкиваться.

Отступ для первого множителя = ширина - количество цифр в первом множителе, для второго аналогично, для знака умножения взять самое длинное число.

Для каждого промежуточного результата отступ будет равен ширина - длина -1, для каждого следующего -1.
немного переписать и будет хорошо

```
public class LongMultiplicationService {
    // Задаем отступ слева
    private static int shiftNumber = 20;

    //  Метод возвращает более длинное из двух чисел
    public static int findLongerNumber(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        int longerNumber = 0;
        if (String.valueOf(firstNumber).length() < String.valueOf(secondNumber).length()) {
            longerNumber = secondNumber;
        } else {
            longerNumber = firstNumber;
        }
        return longerNumber;
    }

    //  Метод возвращает более короткое из двух чисел
    public static int findShorterNumber(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        int shorterNumber = 0;
        if (String.valueOf(firstNumber).length() > String.valueOf(secondNumber).length()) {
            shorterNumber = secondNumber;
        } else {
            shorterNumber = firstNumber;
        }
        return shorterNumber;
    }

    // Метод печатает нужное количество нужных символов подряд без перевода строки в конце
    public static void repeatNSymbols(int n, String symbol) {
        String resultString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            resultString += symbol;
        }
        System.out.print(resultString);
    }

    // Метод печатает нужное количество нужных символов подряд с переводом строки в конце
    public static void repeatNSymbolsNewLine (int n, String symbol) {
        String resultString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            resultString += symbol;

        }
        System.out.print(resultString);
        System.out.println("");
    }

    // Метод печатает промежуточные вычисления - произведения первого числа на каждый из разрядов второго числа
    public static void intermediateMultiplication(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {

        int rightShift = 1;
        while (secondNumber > 0) {
            int number = firstNumber * (secondNumber % 10);
            secondNumber /= 10;
            repeatNSymbols(width - rightShift - String.valueOf(number).length(), " ");
            System.out.println(number);
            rightShift++;
        }
        repeatNSymbols(1, " ");
    }
    static int width =0;
    // Метод сводит всё в одну конструкцию
    public static void printLongMultiplication(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        width =0;
        shiftNumber =20;
        repeatNSymbols(shiftNumber, " ");
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(findLongerNumber(firstNumber, secondNumber)));
        width = shiftNumber + String.valueOf(findLongerNumber(firstNumber, secondNumber)).length();
        repeatNSymbols(shiftNumber - 1, " ");
        System.out.println("x");
        repeatNSymbols(shiftNumber, " ");
        repeatNSymbols(String.valueOf(findLongerNumber(firstNumber, secondNumber)).length() - String.valueOf(findShorterNumber(firstNumber, secondNumber)).length(), " ");
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(findShorterNumber(firstNumber, secondNumber)));
        repeatNSymbols(shiftNumber, " ");
        repeatNSymbolsNewLine(String.valueOf(findLongerNumber(firstNumber, secondNumber)).length(), "_");
        intermediateMultiplication(findLongerNumber(firstNumber, secondNumber), findShorterNumber(firstNumber, secondNumber));
        repeatNSymbols(width -String.valueOf(String.valueOf(firstNumber * secondNumber)).length() -1, " ");
        repeatNSymbolsNewLine(String.valueOf(String.valueOf(firstNumber * secondNumber)).length(), "_");

        repeatNSymbols(width - String.valueOf(firstNumber * secondNumber).length(), " ");
        System.out.println(firstNumber * secondNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: В целом согласен с вами, надо только это в код реализовать. Только надо дополнить введением ветвления if-else, поскольку промежуточные перемножения могут давать число такого же количество разрядов, как и первое число, так и на один разряд большее. В зависимости от этого надо сдвигать влево либо на один пробел, либо на два.

Comment: @VitaliyTretyakov в предложенным мной варианте этого как раз не требуется. (ширина - длина -1) длинна числа будет меняться, потому отступ будет меняться соответствующе. А вот в случае с привязкой к правому краю предсказать длину сложно. Вот при умножении 222 на 90909 будет то 1 число, то 6 и как отступ угадать я даже не знаю

Comment: Да, спасибо. Разобрался - работает. Только делает лишнюю сдвижку влево на 1 пробел. Чтобы пофиксить это, надо rightShift в методе для промежуточных вычислений intermediateMultiplication(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) положить равным нулю: int rightShift = 0; Тогда начального сдвига нет и все выглядит "красиво".